# script to Change ip address format,

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that convert any IP address from CIDR to quad-style.

for example

> 192.168.1.1/24 ===>192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

I tried to write this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter you ip"
read ip
b=`echo $ip | cut -d/ -f1`
a=`echo $ip | cut -d/ -f2`

if a=24 ; then
echo "$b 255.255.255.0"
fi
if a=25; then
echo "$b 255.255.255.128"
fi
```

I'm getting this output:

```
1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
1.1.1.1 255.255.255.128
```

when I'm entering /24 or /25 even /26 that I didn't wrote in if condition, I'm getting same output,
what is wrong in my script?

Comment: i used two variable a,b   
 
a: read just the slash (subnet)  
b: read the ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can use

```
if (( a == 24 )); then
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax for the if

```
if [ $a -eq 24 ];then
```

Answer (score 2):

What `if a=24 ; then` does is to check if the assignment `a=24` was successful or not. Obviously enough, it's always successful (:D), i.e the `if` block is always passing the test.

In Bash you can do:

```
if ((a==24));then
```

Or if you want to be portable, use [David Rosa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063852/3744681)'s method:

```
if [ $a -eq 24 ];then
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a variable's content, you should use $var.

So in your script, instead of testing the content of the variable `a` you are changing it's content.

You should use:

```
if [ $a -eq 24 ]
```

instead of `if a=24`.

I suggest you take a look [here](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/bash-tute.html) to get a good grasp of shell variables.